# Can anyone suggest a small, simple and free bugtracker?

Tags: bug-tracking

I'm looking for a small and simple (emphasis on **simple**) bugtracker for a small project. It should run on Apache/PHP, though I'll consider other alternatives too (no Windows though). Oh, and I don't have any money to spend on it, so it should be free. :P

Any recommendations?

**Added:** Please, no hosted solutions. I want to host it myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). It is free, simple, and runs on Apache.
See the [demosite](http://www.hosted-projects.com/trac/TracDemo/Demo) to try it out yourself.

Comment: ++ for Trac, even though it can be / has been a nightmare to install, especially on older systems. I think that has improved recently, but not sure.

Comment: In addition to bug tracking, Trac also includes a wiki, a subversion browser and great integration between these three parts.

Comment: True, installing it can be a small nightmare. At least, that was my experience when installing it on a Linux server. It could be that I was / am a complete linux newbie, but still :P

Comment: More votes for trac here. The subversion browser there is great, with syntax coloring and very usable revisions browsing and comparing.

Comment: Looks good. I just wonder if a person who has never used a bugtracker before won't feel too overwhelmed... :/

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to get people to use it. XD

Comment: No one will be overwhelmed. It is very low-ceremony. Filing and updating bug reports is super-simple. Much easier than say JIRA or Bugzilla. There is some workflow stuff, but that is all optional.

Comment: Anyplace where I can see it in action? The site doesn't provide screenshots or a demo site of a vanilla installation.

Comment: OK, I think I found its own bug tracking section. Looks nice. OK, it seems I'll try this. :)

Comment: Vilx: http://www.hosted-projects.com/trac/TracDemo/Demo. I included it in my answer. Trac really is one of the most leight-weight bugtrackers available (out of the box) so I really doubt your users will be overwhelmed.

Comment: Emm... basic reading skills FAIL... :D

Comment: OK, I'm convinced. Will try to set this up tonight. :)

Comment: Installed. Actually, it was pretty much a breeze (well, as much as any installation can be a breeze under Linux :P) I suppose that's because under my Debian I could do all the dependancies by apt-get and only install the software itself by dowloading (because Debian doesn't have a package for the latest version yet).

Comment: Glad it worked out for you ok :) If you like it, take a look at http://trac-hacks.org/ - it has a huge number of addons for Trac, some that can be quite useful.

Comment: Alright, looking at it. Actually, it already has a truckload of features that I never thought of but immediately fell in love with. Great tool! Now let's just hope that the MySQL support is stable in the latest version. :)

Answer (score 3):

Written in Perl, but [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) is really easy to setup. The installation is mostly done by the setup script.

Comment: But it's big and complicated. :P

Comment: Not at all. Trac is much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I really like Mantis: http://www.mantisbt.org/ . You can see it in action at http://bugs.scribus.net , for example.

There is much personal taste involved; this is just mine: I think Mantis is simple, still offers you quite a few features, but it doesn't bang you in the head with them. I find it very comfortable to work with.

TBH, I have never used Mantis as and Admin, just as a User / Reporter, but I do suppose that the ease of use continues into the lower level functionality.

Comment: I installed Mantis after only being an user too on a limited (hosted) account. It pretty much was creating a few tables via phpmysqladmin and then running a php script on the (solaris) server, and I already was in business. Still read the docs carefully though, some of the points made in the docs have security relevance.

Answer (score 2):

Pivotal Tracker: http://www.pivotaltracker.com/

It's simple and is great for project management too. It's also hosted and free! No setup. You just need a login.

Comment: I'd like to host it myself, thank you. :)

Comment: Pivotaltracker locks interesting, even if it is hosted. +1 for more than just a table of issues

Answer (score 1):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) has a free, hosted version if you're working alone, or with one other person.

Comment: I wanted to host it myself, and there would be 4 people initially accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Roundup tracker:  http://roundup.sourceforge.net/

- It's free
- It's open source
- It has a built in webserver so can host itself, or do the apache thing
- It can run on top of a database, or just files
- It's written in Python and is insanely hackable if that's your thing
- It has a vibrant community of people writing plugins - e.g wiki like issue editing

Answer (score 0):

Checkout BugTracker.net.

It's easy to use and very much productive.

Comment: Except it's written in .NET. No Windows, remember? And yes - I know of Mono, but it's hardly stable and I already failed at setting it up once.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the happy people in the town of [Simplton](http://simplton.com).

Comment: Interesting, although it's neither free nor can I host it myself on PHP/Apache. :)