# Do you know any free Bug Tracking System?

Tags: c#, .net, bug-tracking

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can anyone suggest a small, simple and free bugtracker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005525/can-anyone-suggest-a-small-simple-and-free-bugtracker)
>   [What is your bug/task tracking tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774/what-is-your-bug-task-tracking-tool)

Hi,

Do you know any free Bug Tracking System that achieves the goals described in [The Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) which says:

A minimal useful bug database must include the following data for every bug:

•complete steps to reproduce the bug

• expected behavior

• observed (buggy) behavior

• who it's assigned to

• whether it has been fixed or not

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774/what-is-your-bug-task-tracking-tool

Comment: Um, all of them? Seriously, that's a very minimal list.

Comment: I agree that it is a kind of dupcilate so I voted it to be closed as well -SO does not let me to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can compare systems here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems